# DNS lookup is not happening

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, php, ssl

I have two identical servers on AWS. On one server when a form is submitted, the network timings are 7.22s. On the other server it is 2.38s.

The code is same on both the servers. The only difference I could find is the DNS lookup.

1. Is DNS lookup delaying the request?
2. Why is this issue occurring on one host and not on the other?

[Network Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9qe3.png)

We tried cross checking Apache modules and found no differences in both.

Comment: What DNS lookup by the way? - The delay appears entirely in the "waiting for server response" timings i.e. waiting for the the code running on the server to generate a response. Why your code runs fatser om one server than on another? I don't have a glue, your code is your own. A five second difference might be the delay caused by something failing and timing out in that code. But you'd expect that a developer generates log messages on errors and a sysadmin to check those logs for anything useful (before doing more thorough profiling)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask